# GCC compiling on Pi for x86_64 linux

Tags: linux, cross-compilation

In using a Raspberry Pi as my development machine - how would I go about compiling a basic C program for running on x86_64 linux?

I see some references to `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc`, but this package is not found when trying to install through apt-get.

```
$ sudo apt-get install x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
E: Unable to locate package x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
```

I also tried specifying -march=x86-64, but this is unrecognized by gcc

```
$ gcc -march=x86-64 test.c
gcc: error: unrecognized -march target: x86-64
```

Comment: You'd need a [cross compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler), but I'd suggest you not pursue this: AFAIK there isn't one available pre-built, and building such on the Pi is likely to be somewhere between nightmarish and impossible.

Comment: Huh, looks like **I'm wrong**:  There is a `gcc-x86-64-linux-gnu` arm64 package in (64-bit) RpiOS/Raspbian.  Can't make any promises but it is worth a try.   I don't see it in the 32-bit RpiOS though.